# How to publish and host MEAN stack project in GitHub

Tags: node.js, express, github, mean-stack, github-pages

How to host AngularJS, MonogDB, Node.js, ExpressJS project on GitHub?
I have uploaded normally like a static HTML page but it didn't work.
How to host this project as it consists of four technologies

Comment: are you planning on setting up a [GitHub Page](https://pages.github.com/)? Or do you want just a local server for MEAN stack to work?

Comment: setting up a github page and host that

Comment: You can't run server code on Github Pages. It's meant for static HTML pages.

Comment: Hoo is there any alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can't host a MEAN stack site on [GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/):

> GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service and doesn't support server-side code such as, PHP, Ruby, or Python.

Similarly, GitHub Pages doesn't support Node.js or MongoDB.

Comment: then how can i do that.Can you please tell me like what the solution to host MEAN stack porject

Comment: How can you do what? It isn't possible to host MEAN on GitHub Pages. You'll have to use another host.

Comment: that's what i am asking the aternative host source for MEAN stack projects

Comment: There are tons of web hosts out there, many of which support that stack. Asking for recommendations of specific off-site resources, like web hosts, is off-topic here; try searching for "mean stack host" and seeing what you find.

Answer (score 0):

Since github pages host only static resources like html, css and javascript you cannot host a node application there. You could try hosting your project on [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/), [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) etc. These provides free trials versions as well. Here you can set up your own server and get things working.